# Install Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 using UEFI boot and third boot as Backtrack 5r3 and grub to select OS at startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have HP g6 Pavilion Laptop and I have installed Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 both in UEFI mode.

While I was installing Ubuntu it didn't detect Windows 8 so I used manual partitioning and it installed successfully.

Then I installed Backtrack 5r3 using normal legacy boot as it does not support EFI boot. It detected Ubuntu but I again used manual partitioning and again it installed properly.

The problem is that when I start my laptop Windows 8 boots directly and I don't get a menu to choose the OS.

I installed GRUB to my Windows partition while installing Ubuntu and Backtrack.

I've tried using Easy BCD for Boot menu but it hasn't helped.

I can start Ubuntu from BIOS from the EFI Boot options as I see an Ubuntu OS EFI file there, but I want a boot menu or GRUB to select the OS.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this problem in many ways, but either of the following is likely to be easiest:

- Boot a live CD-R or USB flash drive in EFI mode and run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This should get GRUB up and running with Windows detected. The trick is forcing an EFI-mode boot of a live CD. You may need to play with your firmware's boot options. Typically, hitting a function key (which one varies) produces a boot menu, and you should select the one for your live CD that mentions "EFI" or "UEFI."
- Download the CD-R or USB flash drive image of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a medium with it. You should then be able to boot to it. If rEFInd lets you boot both Windows and Linux, boot to Linux, mount your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) to `/boot/efi`, and install the Debian-package version of rEFInd. You'll then use rEFInd to select your OS on subsequent boots.

If one of these fails, try the other one. If you continue to have problems, post back with the URL that Boot Repair provides; this will give us detailed information on your system's configuration.

Comment: I just changed my mind....m thinking of installing Linux-Kali instead of Backtrack...so would i b able to load it from rEFInd?

Comment: Yes. rEFInd is a boot manager that launches EFI boot loaders, such as ELILO or GRUB. Since version 3.3.0, the Linux kernel has included an EFI boot loader, effectively turning it into its own boot loader. The worst-case scenario for using rEFInd is that you'd need to add ELILO to the mix, but chances are that Kali includes the EFI stub loader in its kernel. (Most distributions today do so.)

Comment: the latest kali kernel which i downloaded, didn't have efi files...so to boot it using efi boot i added the efi files as mention on kali forums...
i was able to boot using efi mode.

but m not understanding how to use rEFInd...

so plese can u give me the steps of how to use it.

Comment: See the [official rEFInd documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) If something is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: kk I mostly understood what to do from the document... 

But b4 doing that im once again installing the 3 OS again. Because of many errors. 

But m not understanding 1 thing.. as windows create 300 MB EFI partition while installation, do i need to create the efi partition once again while installing ubuntu and kali?

And secondly as i create a swap partition while installing Ubuntu, do i need to create another swap partition while installing Kali?

Or what if i install Ubuntu first then Windows... whats the change if i install in this manner?

Comment: "No" to both questions. The EFI System Partition (ESP) is meant to be shared between OSes. Although you *can* create a separate ESP for each OS, the Windows installer will become confused by this, which could cause problems in the future, so I recommend sticking with just one ESP. Linux swap space can be shared between distributions, with the exception that if you use suspend-to-disk, you should use separate swap partitions. (Using suspend-to-disk is risky with multiple OSes, though, at least if you have any shared partitions, since disk corruption can result.)

Comment: kk Thanks for the help.. I had created 2 ESP partitions.. so Im going to do re-installation..   But Windows by default create 100 MB ESP..  So is it enough? And of what size Swap partition i should  create for ubuntu and kali?

Comment: A ~100MB ESP is probably big enough. The swap partition should generally be at least as big as your RAM, mainly so that you can use suspend-to-disk functionality. Windows will work as "efficiently" no matter when you install it, although if you install Windows second, it will register its boot loader as the primary one, so you'll need to use the firmware's built-in boot manager to boot to Linux and then fix it with `efibootmgr` (type `man efibootmgr` and pay attention to its `-o` option for details).

Comment: Ok..  But how to go to firmware built in Boot Manager?

Comment: That varies from one computer to another. Usually it's by pressing a function key at boot time, although some computers use Esc. A few lack a way to do this.

Comment: OK I will try and tell you about the results..